# How to fix C++ linker error: undefined symbols for architecture?

Tags: makefile

user4581301 and Ted Lyngmo also helped point out another pitfall:

> Rational for Ted's comment: Everyone who includes that header now has using namespace std: forced on them, and if their code's not ready for it they can get mystery errors at runtime when some std::-dwelling function gets called in place of their non-std:: function or at compile time due to ambiguity. Worse, some folk will get errors with some compilers or options and not others. For example C++17 added std::size which may conflict with existing variables named size. Nasty thing to do to someone. – user4581301

I want to compile an executable, lab1_maketest, using PrintMeFirst.hpp, PrintMeFirst.cpp, and lab1_maketest.cpp. I'm using PrintMeFirst.hpp to declare a PrintMeFirst function, then PrintMeFirst.cpp to define that function, and including PrintMeFirst.hpp in lab1_maketest.cpp and calling PrintMeFirst function in lab1_maketest.cpp. I am getting an error when running make

> undefined symbols for architecture Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> "PrintMeFirst(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >)", referenced from:
> _main in lab1_maketest.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

There seems to be something wrong with the way my PrintMeFirst function is being linked or in the way it was created. I don't see the problem though. If I don't try to link the files, and instead just put the PrintMeFirst function into lab1_maketest.cpp and compile that, I have no issues. That's why I think something is wrong with the way it is being linked.

I tried searching for the error message and I found hundreds of results, but I'm a complete beginner when it comes to compiling multiple c++ files (and coding in general) and cannot follow many of the answers on this site. Also many of the answers on this site refer to errors in compilation method, but I've been given a makefile to use by my teacher so I don't think I should be having problems in the makefile.

Here is the code for the 3 files I'm trying to link, and the makefile I'm using.

```
//  PrintMeFirst.hpp

#ifndef PrintMeFirst_hpp
#define PrintMeFirst_hpp
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void PrintMeFirst( string Name, string CourseInfo);

#endif
```

```
//  print_me_first.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include "PrintMeFirst.hpp"

using namespace std;

void PrintMeFirst( string Name, string CourseInfo){
    cout << "Program written by: " << Name << endl;
    cout << "Course Info: " << CourseInfo << endl;
    time_t now = time(0);
    char* dt = ctime(&now);
    cout << "Date: " << dt << endl;
}
```

```
//  lab1_maketest.cpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include "PrintMeFirst.hpp"

int main() {
    PrintMeFirst("My Name", "Title of assignment"); // this one is not working
    question(); // function handled in this cpp itself
    conversion(SInput, temp); // again handled within this cpp
}
```

```
// makefile
#
#
CC=g++
#
#CFLAGS = -c -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql 
#LFLAGS = -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient

CFLAGS = -c -Wall  
LFLAGS =  


all: lab1_maketest

vectorstructTax: lab1_maketest.o PrintMeFirst.o 
    $(CC) lab1_maketest.o PrintMeFirst.o  -o lab1_maketest $(LFLAGS)


lab1_maketest.o: lab1_maketest.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) lab1_maketest.cpp

PrintMeFirst.o: PrintMeFirst.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) PrintMeFirst.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o lab1_maketest

run:
    ./lab1_maketest
```

If anyone wants I could also post the whole cpp that actually works.

Comment: Typo: `#include "PrintMeFirst.hpp"` doesn't align with print_me_first.hpp. When folk try to build and run and find that it doesn't compile, some will jump on this and say, "Once I fix this it's perfect." If they go that far. Make the examples 100% reproducible without modification and things generally turn out better. Ditto `question` and `conversion`. If you don't need them in the example, remove them. If it turns out you do need them, find out why.

Comment: Unrelated: Never do `using namespace std;` in header files. Also, don't include more than you need. `#include <stdio.h>` isn't needed in `PrintMeFirst.hpp` for example. I don't see any need for it anywhere in the program actually.

Comment: @user4581301 You've got a keen eye, that typo is left over from when I tried making the function name match the .hpp and .cpp file names exactly. It didn't work whether the function name matched the file name or not. And I got the same error. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'll keep that in mind from now on

Comment: Rational for Ted's  comment: Everyone who includes that header now has `using namespace std:` forced on them, and if their code's not ready for it they can get mystery errors at runtime when some `std::`-dwelling function gets called in place of their non-`std::` function or at compile time due to ambiguity.  Worse, some folk will get errors with some compilers or options and not others. For example C++17 added `std::size` which may conflict with existing variables named `size`. Nasty thing to do to someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the target `lab1_maketest` which is not defined in your makefile:

Replace:

```
vectorstructTax: lab1_maketest.o PrintMeFirst.o
```

By:

```
lab1_maketest: lab1_maketest.o print_me_first.o
```

Also, check all the names: some typos between `PrintMeFirst` instead of `print_me_first`.

Finally, calling some undefined/undeclared functions:

```
question(); // This does not exist
conversion(...); // this does not exist neither
```

Final result:

makefile

```
#
#
CC=g++
#
#CFLAGS = -c -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql 
#LFLAGS = -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient

CFLAGS = -c -Wall  
LFLAGS =  


all: lab1_maketest

lab1_maketest: lab1_maketest.o print_me_first.o 
    $(CC) lab1_maketest.o print_me_first.o  -o lab1_maketest $(LFLAGS)


lab1_maketest.o: lab1_maketest.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) lab1_maketest.cpp

PrintMeFirst.o: print_me_first.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) print_me_first.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o lab1_maketest

run:
    ./lab1_maketest
```

> Carefull: makefile needs tabs, no space (but stackoverflow replace them by spaces).

lab1_maketest.cpp

```
//  lab1_maketest.cpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include "print_me_first.hpp"

int main() {
    PrintMeFirst("My Name", "Title of assignment"); // this one is not working
}
```

print_me_first.hpp and print_me_first.cpp are unchanged.

Comment: Ah man thank you so much, I'm so embarrassed... really appreciate the extra eyes!

Comment: You are welcome @KshitijSharma. Please don't forget to approve the answer (the V at the left side of the answer, bellow the score; this allows others to know that the question is already answered.